# Managing a configuration file using sed via shell script

Tags: shell, configuration, sed, read-write

I need to manage a configuration file in Linux using a shell script, that will read and write settings to and from the `cfg` file. I have following function to write a new `value` of a `key` in existing config file used in my script.

```
set_setting() {
    sed -i "s/$1=[^ ]*/$1=$2/" $3
}
```

Usage:

`set_setting keyname NewValue /home/Config.cfg`

Thus, this would replace the value of `keyname` in `Config.cfg` to `NewValue`.

I also have a function `get_setting` which uses `source` command to read the config file. It accepts similarly two parameters, `keyname` and the source config file, and returns the `value` of the supplied key.

Now the problem is that, I have config file as follows.

```
name=Abc
surname=Xyz
```

And when I call the `set_setting` function as `set_setting name Def /home/Config.cfg`, ideally it should change value of `name` from `Abc` to `Def`, but along with changing value of key `name`, it also changes the value of `surname` from `Xyz` to `Def` resulting into following in config file.

```
name=Def
surname=Def
```

I suspect this is due to having the term "name" common in both keys, as when I changed the key `surname` to `surnames`, it worked as expected and only value of `name` was changed. Also note that, the value for the key can be anything except the space.

I'm new to shell scripting and recently discovered `sed` command.

I've also refered to SO questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082102/how-to-serach-and-replace-a-content-of-a-file-using-shell-script) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891342/modify-conf-file-with-shell-script). While both of them were quite helpful, I'm stuck with above mentioned situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should anchor your match to the beginning of the line:

```
 sed -i "s/^$1=[^ ]*/$1=$2/" $3
```

Note the `^` in front of `$1`. This regex operator anchors the expression to the beginning of the line, effectively requiring the name being everything from the first character to the `=` sign. There's also an end-of-line anchor called `$` (which you do not need here).

Comment: Stupid I was. :-) Thanks a lot!